# A strongly non-integrable distribution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, foliations

What  is  an  example  of  a  three-dimensional  smooth  distribution  $D$ of  $\mathbb{R}^4$  with this  property:

> Not  only $D$ is not integrable  but also there is  no  a  two-dimensional  foliation  $F$ of  $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that for  every $x\in \mathbb{R}^4$, the  tangent space  to each  leaf at $x$ is  contained  in $D_x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294517/is-there-a-2-dimensional-foliation-tangent-to-this-particular-3-dimensional) as been answered, we can answer this original question:  The answer is 'yes' there exists a non-integrable tangent $3$-plane field on $\mathbb{R}^4$ that has no subordinate co-dimension $2$-foliation.

It suffices to take an open $p$-neighborhood $U$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ of a point $p$ that lies on the line $L$ described in my answer to that question.  Then choosing a diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^4\to U$, set $\beta = \phi^*\alpha$.  Then $\ker\beta$ will be a non-integrable tangent $3$-plane field on $\mathbb{R}^4$ that has no subordinate co-dimension $2$-foliation, because there is no such foliation on a neighborhood of $\phi^{-1}(p)$.

Of course, this says nothing about the following more precise question:  Let $\beta$ be a $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\beta\wedge\mathrm{d}\beta$ is nowhere vanishing.  Must there exist a co-dimension $2$ foliation of $\mathbb{R}^4$ whose leaves are all $\beta$-null?

Comment: Thanks  for  this  answer  and  very  interesting question in the last part of your  answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe  the standard example $dz - ydx = 0$ does the trick.
This is the normal form for what many people call a ``quasi-contact distribution'-the even dimensional analogue of a contact form.  Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $F$ is one of your foliations and $L$
the leaf of $F$ through a point $x$.   Then the pull back
of the above  oneform to $L$ is zero.
But $d$ of the one form is $dx \wedge dy$, which, restricted to the distribution, is a rank 2 form, and so cannot have $T_x L = F_x$ in  its kernel.
Contradiction.

Comment: Richard, your example doesn't really work, as I understand it:  If the full coordinate system on $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $(x,y,z,w)$, then the codimension-$2$ foliation $F$ defined by $\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}z=0$ is an example of the kind that Ali wants not to be possible for the distribution $D$ defined by $\mathrm{d}z - y\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  thank for your comment.I think that every $1$ form which is independent of $w$ does not work,too.Yes? Just another question: Assume that $\alpha$ is a $1$_form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\alpha \wedge d\alpha= i(X) \Omega$ for some non vanihing vector field $X$ and the volum form $\Omega$. Can such $\alpha$ possess a tangent 2 dimensional foliation?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  The answers to your two comment questions above are 'yes' and 'yes'.  For the second question, you used 'Can'.  If you had used 'Must', I wouldn't know the answer.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you for  your  attention  and your  comment,

Comment: @RichardMontgomery  Thank you  very much for  your  attention to my question. I would  appreciate  if  you let me know if you find a revised counter example.

Comment: Robert, thanks for pointing out my foolishness. I guess as long as you have a `Cartan characteristic' direction W - a vector field  like $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$ in the normal form which is tangent to $D$ and such that $L_W D \subset D$, then by taking  any integral curve to $D$ which is transverse to $W$ and pushing it forward by the flow of $W$ one builds such an   integral  surface.

Comment: @RichardMontgomery:  Yes, that always works locally.  The question being asked is only nontrivial as a global question.